# Is there any limitations for oxyplot line graph refresh rate?

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I'm plotting two Line Graphs using the Oxyplot Library in a WPF application, which works pretty well. There are a maximum of 8 lines, but for the sake of the test, I'm only using 2.

The program allows the user to choose the refresh rate of the data, which is also used to refresh both Plots. All works as it should, unless when the user choose a Refresh rate under 1 second.

Some seconds after the refresh has been set to under 1 sec, the Plot just vanishes and its area turns blank. A weird fact tho, the Tracker still works if I can find the right spot in the line, i.e. the points of the graph are still there, but it's not been shown anymore. It happens first with one Graph, than some time later the second Graph also turns into a deep white area.

I wonder, is there any limitation for the refresh rate for Line Graphs of the Oxyplot library? I mean, does it use some buffer or cache memory that is probably been blown by the high refresh rate? And yes, I would need it to refresh this fast in some cases.